# Ruby on Rails 6 Webpack with Javascript libraries

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, webpack

I am building a new project in Rails 6. I have a front-end library I want to use (`@tarekraafat/autocomplete.js`) that is installed by yarn and exists in my `node_modules` directory, but is not being made available to other JS code in the browser. Here is what I have set up currently:

`/package.json`:

```json
"dependencies": {
  "@tarekraafat/autocomplete.js": "^8.2.1"
}
```

`/app/javascript/packs/application.js`:

```js
import "@tarekraafat/autocomplete.js/dist/js/autoComplete.min.js"
```

`/app/views/.../example.html.erb`

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = () => {
    new autoComplete({
      [...]
    });
  };
</script>
```

I am getting an error in the browser pointing to the `new autoComplete()`:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: autoComplete is not defined

Some reading seems to indicate that I need to modify the `/config/webpack/environment.js` file, in which I have tried various versions of the following with no luck (including restarting the dev server):

`/config/webpack/environment.js`:

```js
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')

const webpack = require('webpack')
environment.plugins.prepend('Provide',
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        autoComplete: 'autocomplete.js'
    })
);

module.exports = environment
```

First, what do I need to do to add this library so it can be used correctly? Second, as someone who has not directly used webpack previously, what is the function of adding this definition to the `environments.js` file, and why don't I need to do it for some libraries (bootstrap, popper) but I do for others (jquery, and maybe autocomplete.js)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Webpacker, the usage of this library would be as follows:

```js
// app/javascript/src/any_file.js

import autoComplete from "@tarekraafat/autocomplete"

new autoComplete(...)


// app/javascript/packs/application.js

import "../src/any_file"
```

This alone does not import the `autoComplete` variable into the global scope. To do that, the simplest thing is assign the variable to `window` from within your webpack dependency graph.

```js
// app/javascript/src/any_file.js

import autoComplete from "@tarekraafat/autocomplete"

window.autoComplete = autoComplete
```

As an aside, you don't need to use the `ProvidePlugin` configuration for this library. The ProvidePlugin says: “add this import to all files in my dependency graph.” This might be helpful for something like jQuery to make legacy jQuery plugins work in webpack. It is not necessary to make your autocomplete lib work

Comment: Thank you! I can't import in the usage location because it's embedded javascript in HTML, but I did the import in `/app/javascript/packs/...` and do the `window.`assign there, which brought it into scope for the embedded JS. What is the context in which plugins need to be declared in the `environment.js` file?

Comment: Look closely, my example is part of the webpack dependency graph, not embedded html.

Comment: Updated my answer with regards to the ProvidePlugin.

Comment: I was misreading the import as a necessary step put in an external JS file to expose the library to the embedded JS scope, but I see now that it is just an example of how to access the library if needed from a file in that location. Thanks for the update on ProvidePlugin, makes sense!